# properties not binding to template in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

i got data from Apex method and trying to bind to template by using property, data is not shown in UI and No errors happened. simple logic but killing my time to resolving. can you help me for where i did wrong.

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import gettransporterByCase from '@salesforce/apex/IMS_EventInfo.gettransporterByCase';

export default class IMS_EventReporter extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
caseUserMapresp;
@track caseInfo = {};
@track userinfo= {};

@wire(gettransporterByCase,{caseId: '$recordId'})
wiredCaseReporterMap(serverResp){
    this.caseUserMapresp = serverResp;
    if (serverResp.data) {
        this.caseInfo = serverResp.data.Case[0];
        this.userinfo = serverResp.data.User[0];
        this.error = undefined;
    }
    else if (serverResp.error){
        this.error = serverResp.error;
        this.caseInfo = undefined;
        this.userinfo = undefined;
    }
}

get reporterrecid(){
    return this.caseInfo.Reporter__c; 
}
get loggedinprofilename(){
    return this.userinfo.Profile.Name;
}
```

**html**

```
<template>   
   hello,{reporterrecid}
   hello,{caseInfo.Reporter__c}
</template>
```

**Update**

i updated the template but now out put is nothing, even "hello," message also not dis plying.
what i observed property break point is not hitting idk why.
   [image]
**output**
[image]

**UPDATE**
what i observed `reporterrecid` property break point hits only one time that time `caseInfo` is `undefined`

**UPDATE** 
it's working after i  assign a empty object to `caseInfo;` -- @track caseInfo = {};
[image]

Comment: The property does not have `@track`, so it's not reactive

Comment: Check the case of the getter, the code you pasted says "reporterrecId" and in the console it says "reporterrecid"

Comment: More on @SebastianKessel's comment - not only is this not tracked, there doesn't really seem a point to it. Why not simply use caseInfo.Reporter__c in the template (which should react since this.caseInfo is itself tracked).

Comment: I am on calls, but one of you should post your answers below... :)

Comment: Updated property name with case sensitive and add another property to in template now nothing is displaying

Comment: You still have a discrepancy between the template and the JS in the snippet you posted. And, if you see nothing, check the console

Comment: sorry updated question again , but why my `reporterrecid` break point hits only one time when `caseinfo` was `undefined`

Comment: it's working after assign empty object to @track caseinfo `@track caseinfo = {};`

Answer (score 2):

Check the case of the getter, the code you pasted says "reporterrecId" and in the console it says "reporterrecid"

Comment: That alone should fix the problem. JS properties are *case sensitive*

Comment: I doubt it will - this isn't a tracked property so only its initial value (undefined) will render into the template.

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer. you don't need to add a @track to getter methods. They'll update the page if they reference a tracked variable themselves, which this one does.

Comment: i updated template  with  `reporterrecid`  still value is not binding in UI.

Comment: @stackasaur is correct, that's why I mentioned that in my comment

Answer (score 0):

This property is not tracked. As such its initial value, undefined, will be rendered into the template on first pass. When it is set, during the wire response handling, there is nothing to kick the re-rendering of the template.

Either make it tracked using:

```
@track get reporterrecId(){
    return this.caseInfo.Reporter__c; 
}
```

and fix the case mis-match, or try changing your template to:

```
<template>   
   hello,{caseInfo.Reporter__c}
</template>
```

Comment: @track as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_decorators): "If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a **getter** of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value."

Comment: Ah, that change in Spring '20 where all "fields" are automatically tracked... I need to have a play with this new behaviour.

Comment: It's actually been the case with not needed to add @track to getter methods which reference a tracked property for a while.

I'm not sure what they're on about with "automatically tracked" though.... I just made a component to test this with a button toggling it's label to match a Boolean value it's updating and it doesn't work unless tracked.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe this is just a null pointer issue.

`@wire` is asynchronous, meaning it is calling back after your page renders, thus your `caseInfo` and `userInfo` variables aren't set by the time your getter method is trying to render them the first time.

And so, `this.caseInfo.Reporter__c` is a null pointer since `this.caseInfo` isn't set. Not really sure why you aren't getting an error message though.

Anyway, you should be able to modify both getters to reflect this

```
get reporterrecid(){
    if (this.caseInfo)
        return this.caseInfo.Reporter__c; 
    return ''; // or null or whatever
}
```